# Redirecting a python code output to a file and rotating it every day

Tags: python, shell, ubuntu, logging, rotation

I want to write a shell script that executes a python script and redirects its output with a timestamp to a **different** log file every day. The python script should run forever without stopping, it prints small text to the terminal every 10 seconds.

Here is how far I have come:

```
filename="log-$(date +%Y-%m-%d).log"
python3 -u HelloWord_every10secs.py 2>&1 | 
while IFS= read -r line; 
    do echo "$(date +%x__%H:%M:%S:%3N) $line"; 
    filename="log-$(date +%Y-%m-%d).log"
    done >> "log/$filename" #u unbuffered  output, for logging, add time stuff
```

This small code redirects the output of the python code to a log file in log/ directory and ads timestamps. The only issue that is missing it cannot rotate the log file over each day with a different date ending.
I except to have in log/ directory:

```
log-2022-11-20.log
log-2022-11-21.log
log-2022-11-22.log
... etc.
```

But I have only one with the date when I run the script.
I know that there is a Ubuntu built-in solution called `lograte` for these things, but I would like to solve this problem without that.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than controlling log files externally, I would recommend using [`TimedRotatingFileHandler`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.handlers.html#timedrotatingfilehandler) instead.

Example:

```py
import logging
from logging.handlers import TimedRotatingFileHandler

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def init_file_handler(log_path, logger=None):
    handler = TimedRotatingFileHandler(log_path, when='midnight')
    handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(message)s'))
    if logger is None:
        logger = logging.getLogger()  # This will be the root logger, which will capture all logs
    logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)  # Write INFO and above; use DEBUG or NOTSET for more
    logger.addHandler(handler)
```

Using the above, if we run this:

```py
>>> init_file_handler('test.log')

>>> log.info('foo')
```

The result will be:

```bash
$ cat test.log
2022-11-20 07:43:32,785 foo
```

The first log line written after midnight will trigger the roll-over, where `test.log` from this example would be renamed to `test.log.2022-11-20`, and a new `test.log` would be created.

It is possible to change the [time format in the logged events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220284/how-to-customize-the-time-format-for-python-logging) (and the overall format of each line), and it is also possible to [adjust the date format for old log files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/338450/timedrotatingfilehandler-changing-file-name).

Additional resources:

- https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html#logging-basic-tutorial
- [Python TimedRotatingFileHandler logs to a file and stderr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6565256/python-timedrotatingfilehandler-logs-to-a-file-and-stderr)

Comment: Thanks for a suggestion, I put it as backup solution if controlling them exeternally is not possible.

Comment: Counter point: why have 2 moving parts instead of 1?  If you want the non-timestamped content on stdout/stderr, you can configure a different formatter for stdout/err compared to the one used for the file.  It's generally easier to maintain something like this if you don't need to maintain a separate wrapper script in a different programming language.